# Facebook "Like" button in ExpressionEngine entries no working correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, expressionengine, social-media

I am building a News section for a client website (in ExpressionEngine) and they have requested that each article have the Facebook like button. So I went to Facebook's developer site and found the necessary code to make it work.

The problem I have is that if I like one article, it counts that like for all of them! I'm using my ee tags for title and permalink in the OpenGraph meta tags, but to no avail.

Open graph code:

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="news" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="1" disable="member_data|trackbacks"}
    <meta property="og:title" content="{title}" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="non_profit" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="{title_permalink=news/article}" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://dallascityhomes.net/_images/dch-logo-big.png" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Dallas City Homes" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="--removed--" />
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

The actual button (it is wrapped within a exp:weblog:entry tag):

```
                <div>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/share?text={title}" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
                    <fb:like href="{title_permalink=news/article}" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="80" font="arial"></fb:like>
                </div>
```

And of course the JS script for FB like, I moved to the bottom of the doc:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the og:url meta property and the href property of the fb:like tag appear to be rendering correctly when you view source?

Comment: Yep, my ee tags populate the correct URL in both of these places... but when you click "like" it does not display the title properly and defaults to the site domain URL instead of the specific URL of the entry. You can try it out yourself: http://dallascityhomes.net/index2.php?/news/article/news_article_headline/

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a FB issue, not an EE issue. (The Tweet button works just fine.)  I'd suggest trying out the iframe-based Like button and see if that works. It's much simpler.

Comment: Yep, it looks like the iFrame version works, but it lacks some of the functionality, like the ability of the user to post it on their wall... Oh well, better something than nothing! Thanks D-Rock!